# Best Unique Identifier for a system

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I have an application that will take the active MACID while installing and save it in the system. and while running the software it will compare the Active MACID of the system wit the saved one. 
But while changing the connection mode (eg: lan adapter to WLAN) the active MACID will change and the software will not work. How to make it working woth MACID OR is there any other unique id for the system to use for the same criteria ?????

Comment: So, you want to annoy your legitimate users when they change some of their hardware? Most protection schemes *only* serve to annoy your legitimate users - and the more draconian they become, the more likely that your users will switch to either a competitor or the cracked version of your software - because it makes their lives easier than dealing with your access control restrictions.

Comment: I also hope you know that you can change the MAC address of a network adapter easily...

Comment: Yes i know, so is there any idea to prevent the copying of software ??